# How do I hide a button in view using MVC 3 when a certain part of a page loads? ie browsecategory schoolbooks

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Hello I am trying to use paypal buttons on my MVC e-commerce site based on the MVC musicstore tutorial. I am loading specific data from a database so I want to have a single button with a dropdown menu for each category in my site. I want to know how to hide one button when the school books category is up and show it again when the stationary category is up so I only have the specific button for that category visible at anyone time. So basically when the view directs to browse school books category I only want the school books button visble. my code is as follows

Store Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Browse(string category)
    {
        // Retrieve Category and its Associated Products from database
        var categoryModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Products")
        .Single(c => c.Name == category);

        return View(categoryModel);


    }
```

Browse View:

```
@model WholeschoolStore3.Models.Category

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Browse Categorys";
}

<div class="product">
<h3><em>@Model.Name</em> Products</h3>

<ul id="Product-list">
    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = product.ProductId })">
                <img alt="@product.ProductName" src="@product.ProductUrl" />
                <span>@product.ProductName</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
<form target="paypal" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value=""/>
School Books<select name="os0">
<option value="History Book">History Book €38.99 EUR</option>
<option value="Biology Book">Biology Book €34.99 EUR</option>
<option value="Math Book">Math Book €39.99 EUR</option>
<option value="Geography Book">Geography Book €34.99 EUR</option>
<option value="Business Studies Book">Business Studies Book €37.99 EUR</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR"/>
<input type="image" src=""  
 width="1" height="1"/>
<img alt="" border="0" src=""    
 width="1" height="1"/>


</form>
<form target="paypal" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Stationary"/>Stationary<select name="os0">
<option value="Pencil">Pencil €0.49 EUR</option>
<option value="Pen">Pen €0.89 EUR</option>
<option value="A4 Refill pad">A4 Refill pad €3.99 EUR</option>
</select> 
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR"/>
<input type="image" src=""
border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>      
<img alt="" border="0" src=""  
 width="1" height="1"/>
</form>



</div>
```

I have tried a number of posts and have not found what i am looking for

Any help would be much appreciated Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using jquery/javascript. On the basis of option selected you can hide and show any button you want .

Please refer the example. In this example button will hide if you select the option Pen €0.89 EUR in rest of the cases it will show

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("select").change(function () {
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                if ($(this).text()=='Pen €0.89 EUR' )
                   $("#btnGo").hide();
                else
                   $("#btnGo").show();
              });
        })
        .trigger('change');
        });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <select name="os0">
        <option value="Pencil">Pencil €0.49 EUR</option>
        <option value="Pen">Pen €0.89 EUR</option>
        <option value="A4 Refill pad">A4 Refill pad €3.99 EUR</option>
        </select> 
        <input id="btnGo" type="button" value="Hi" />
        </body>
        </html>
```

Also your html has some problem
first select 
           
is closed before the option is begin 
it should be like

```
School Books<select name="os0">
<option value="History Book">History Book €38.99 EUR</option>
<option value="Biology Book">Biology Book €34.99 EUR</option>
<option value="Math Book">Math Book €39.99 EUR</option>
<option value="Geography Book">Geography Book €34.99 EUR</option>
<option value="Business Studies Book">Business Studies Book €37.99 EUR</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I dont want the button to appear and disappear when something is selected in the dropdown menu I want the first button(school books) to be shown only when the browse category (school books) is shown from the database and then be gone when the category changes. Is this possible

Comment: Thanks for the help with the Html probelm

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to sort out probelm I was having I just added a div then hid it then added a checkbox that when clicked showed the div the code is as follows:

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $('#ShowHideMe').hide();
             $('#myCheckbox').change(function () {
                 $('#ShowHideMe').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
             });
         });
</script>

     <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox"/>SchoolBooks
<div id="ShowHideMe">                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   //form code here
</div>    
<br />

   <script  type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
           $('#ShowHideMe1').hide();
           $('#myCheckbox1').change(function () {
               $('#ShowHideMe1').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
           });
       });
 </script>

     <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox1"/>Stationary
 <div id="ShowHideMe1">
      //form code here
 </div>
```

Thanks for the help to anyone who responded

By the way I lost the password to my other account so had to make a new one thats why im replying as a different user